# Async code running - using Javascript OOP in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, javascript-objects, es6-class

I'm working on a react-native project, and to make users manipulation easier, I created a class User, which connect to the firebase database to get all informations about the user (ex: the name).

But I have an issue, the code run asynchronously. If I want to do :

```
User.getCurrentUser().alertName(); // Display "undefined"
```

The `alertName()` function runs before the User class constructor, in which is initialized the name, so this line just log "undefined".

Here is User class :

```
class User {

    uid;
    object;
    name;

    constructor(id){

        firebase.database().ref('/user/'+id).once('value').then( function (snapshot) {

            this.object = snapshot.val();

            this.uid = id;
            this.name = this.object.name;

            console.log("In constructor : " + this.name);
        });
    }

    alertName(){
        console.log("From function : " + this.name);
    }

    static getCurrentUser(){
        let id = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
        return new User(id);
    }
}
```

When trying to do:

```
User.getCurrentUser().alertName();
```

Console log:

> From function : undefined
>   From constructor : John

The function runs before the constructor, so of course the name is undefined...

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Side effects in constructor can be considered an antipattern, this is the case for asynchronous code, exactly because the result won't be available right after class instantiation.

A promise should be exposed:

```
constructor(id){
    const initPromise = Promise.resolve(firebase.database().ref('/user/'+id).once('value').then( function (snapshot) {...});
}

alertName(){...}
```

And either chained manually:

```
const user = User.getCurrentUser();
await user.initPromise;
user.alertName();
```

Or chained internally:

```
async alertName(){
  await this.initPromise();
  ...
}
```

and

```
const user = User.getCurrentUser();
await user.alertName();
```

This is the case where OOP design doesn't have much benefits. Since React already encourages functional programming, it could be more straightforward without a class.

Answer (score 0):

```
class User {

    uid;
    object;
    name;

    constructor(id){

        return firebase.database().ref('/user/'+id).once('value').then( function (snapshot) {

            this.object = snapshot.val();

            this.uid = id;
            this.name = this.object.name;
            console.log("In constructor : " + this.name);
            return this;
        });
    }

    alertName(){
        console.log("From function : " + this.name);
    }

    static getCurrentUser(){
        let id = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
        return new User(id);
    }
```

and now while calling it do something like

---

`User.getCurrentUser().then(user => user.alertName());`

---

So, what happening here is we are returning a promise from constructor which after calling database gets resolved with `uid, name and object` in then and we are returning this i.e. `User` from this promise. So, when we will do `User.getCurrentUser()` we will get a promise which resolves with actual current user and on resolve we will call `alertName` method of currentUser.

Comment: The idea works, because the console logs "In constuctor" first. But I have an error about the promise : "[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'user.alertName')]"